# Visualforce - add thousand separator in barSeries chart

Tags: visualforce, charts

i need to put a thousand separator in the tooltip of the bar in a chart eg: 400000 -> 400,000, but so far i couldn't find how to do it. Searching on the internet i find a way to do it with the numbers on the left of the chart using rerenderFn, but i couldn't replicate it as i want to do it.
Any ideas?

this is how it looks right now, i need to format the number in the tooltip.

[image]

Here is the visualforce code, and the info its sended in a object like `data:[{name:august, data:4000},...]`

```
<apex:page controller="ChartsmetricasMarketplace">
<apex:slds />
<input type="hidden" name="currentvfpage2" value="{!$CurrentPage.Name}"/>
<apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(data == null,True,False)}" style="font-weight:800" escape="false">No hay metricas para este Seller</apex:outputText>
<apex:chart height="400" width="100%" data="{!data}" rendered="{!IF(data != null,True,False)}">
      <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="data" 
        title="BGMV LC" grid="true">
      </apex:axis>/>
      <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="name" 
        title="Meses">
    </apex:axis>
    <apex:barSeries axis="left" xField="name" yField="data" orientation="vertical" colorSet="FCED00"/>
 </apex:chart>
</apex:page>
```